# SQL - Count new entries based on last date

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table with the follow structure

```
ID  ReportDate  Object_id
```

What I need to know, is the count of new and count of old (Object id's)

***For example: If I have the data below:***

[image]

I want the following output grouped by `ReportDate`:

[image]

I thought a way doing it using a Where clause based on date, however i need the data for all the dates I have in the table. To see the count of what already existed in the previous report and what is new at that report. Any Ideas?

Edit: New/Old definition- New would be the records that never appeared before that report run date and appeared on this one, whereas old is the number of records that had at least one match in previous dates. I'll edit the post to include this info.

Comment: How computer will detect which one is new and which one old?

Comment: Hi Harun, new would be the records that never appeared before that report run date and appeared on this one, whereas old is the number of records that had at least one match in previous dates. I'll edit the post to include this info.

Comment: As per your definition how 19/08/2020 new 2 and old is 1? Can you please clarify?

Comment: Means that Obj_B is there but it has already appeared in the past so it is considered as 1 old distinct obj_id, and Obj_D and Obj_E are new occurrences hence two new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

managed to do it using a left join. Below is my solution in case it helps anyone in the future :)

```
SELECT table.ReportRunDate,
-1*sum(table.ReportRunDate = new_table.init_date) as count_new,
-1*sum(table.ReportRunDate <> new_table.init_date) as count_old,
count(*) as count_total


FROM table LEFT JOIN 
((SELECT Object_ID, min(ReportRunDate) as init_date
FROM table
GROUP By OBJECT_ID) as new_table)
ON table.Object_ID = new_table.Object_ID

GROUP BY ReportRunDate
```

Answer (score -1):

This would work in Oracle, not sure about ms-access:

```
SELECT ReportDate
      ,COUNT(CASE WHEN rnk = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) count_of_new
      ,COUNT(CASE WHEN rnk <> 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)count_of_old
FROM (SELECT ID
            ,ReportDate
            ,Object_id
            ,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Object_id ORDER BY ReportDate) rnk
        FROM table_name)
GROUP BY ReportDate
```

Inner query should rank each occurence of object_id based on the ReportDate so the 1st occurrence of certain object_id will have rank = 1, the next one rank = 2 etc.
Then the outer query counts how many records with rank equal/not equal 1 are the within each group.

I assumed that 1 object_id can appear only once within each reportDate.

Comment: CASE and RANK are not implemented into access I can use switch instead of case, but don't know how to handle the RANK()